# Getting Sha256 values in any arbitrary range with almost equal probability

Tags: sha-256

I went through this post [SHA256 output to 1-6 number range?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76406/sha256-output-to-1-6-number-range), this post, [SHA256 output to 0-99 number range?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17990/sha256-output-to-0-99-number-range) and I felt like the exact way mentioned in the first one is really helpful. I am looking for help to generalize the way for any arbitrary integer, in other words, if we want the output values in range of 0 to n where any output may get any value in the range with equal probability, how would I apply the exact way mentioned in the first post? Or is there any other way which helps?

Comment: The answer is given in SO [Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/1820553). The keyword is the _discarding_.

Comment: I've added the general case to the 0-99 question, now it should handle your question. If not, notify us.

Comment: Thanks so much @kelalaka :) This answers my question I believe :)